# Occur Memory Leak, when create object using 'new' on android

Tags: java, android, memory, memory-leaks

recently I work reducing memory leak on my android source.

I use allocation tracking tool on android studio

my app is recording camera preview app

[image]

if you look at the picture

```
protected int getOutPutBufferIndex() {
       IMediaCodec.BufferInfo bufferInfo = new IMediaCodec.BufferInfo(); //here occur memory leak
       int outputBufferIndex = mediaCodec.dequeueOutputBuffer(bufferInfo, timeout); //get buffer index
       return outputBufferIndex;
}
```

this method only return buffer index.

I guess  occur memory leak when create object using `new`

so I try add `bufferInfo = null;` on `return outputBufferIndex;`

but `bufferInfo = null;` the assigned to never used message.

and occur memory leak unchanged.

so, How to when create object using `new` , avoid memory leak on android?

thanks.

Comment: That doesn't look like `C++` it looks like `Java`.

Comment: From that image, I see `java` mentioned.  This is not `C++`

Comment: sorry, I add mentioned mistake

Answer (score 0):

try Using MediaCodec.BufferInfo with new operator assignment.it should remove your error..

Comment: thanks, `IMediaCodec` is override `MediaCodec. usually, object clear I use `object = null` but my source not work.